# ¿Por qué no se paginan los datos de 10 en 10? JavaScript Random User

Tags: javascript, jquery

De este link https://randomuser.me/api/?results=34 tengo que crear una tabla con solo un div #root y con una páginación de 10 en 10

34 elementos 
4 páginas
1era = 10 elementos;
2da = 10 elementos;
3era = 10 elementos;
4ta = 4 elementos;

Tengo todo hecho, pero los elementos no se dividen como arriba
Si no que en cada página me dan 34 elementos.
Ayuda por favor.
**Y aquí en JS**

```
const pagination = {
    pageSize : 10,
    currentPage : 1,
    totalPages : 0,
    totalItems : 34
}


function fetchData() {
        setLoading(true);

        fetch(`${API}&limit=${pagination.pageSize}&offset=${pagination.pageSize * (pagination.currentPage - 1)}`)
            .then(data => {
                console.log("data desde el server", data);
                data.json().then(results => {
                    dataResults = results;
                    pagination.pageSize = 10;
                    pagination.totalItems = 34;
                    pagination.totalPages = calculateTotalPages();
                    console.log("results", dataResults);
                    span.textContent=`${pagination.currentPage} de ${pagination.totalPages}`;
                    console.log(calculateTotalPages());
                    BuildTable();
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log("error", error);
                }).finally(() => {
                    //código cuando termina la promesa
                    setLoading(false);
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("error", error);
                setLoading(false);
            })
    }
```

Comment: Tu consulta no es acorde a la documentación de la API que intentas consumir. Por favor lee primero dicha documentación. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

si eliminas el parametro results=34 de la consulta te funciona.

```
https://randomuser.me/api/?limit=10&offset=10
```

Aunque no hay forma de comprobar que el offset funciona, ya que si te da siempre una lista aleatoria de usuarios estes varían a cada consulta. Deberías de obtener los resultados que quieras y luego usar tu la paginación sin llamar a la api.

Comment: Hola que tal, con eso no logro solucionarlo tampoco):

Comment: Viendo la documentación de la api, https://randomuser.me/documentation#pagination, tienes que poner en results el tamaño de la página, en page la página que quieres ver y luego añadir el parámetro seed, que te lo devuelve en la propiedad info de cada búsqueda. Está tiene que ser siempre la misma, si no los datos nunca serán los mismos